# Вопрос по регистру при обработке кода php

Tags: php

На сайте есть тестовое задание. Правильный ответ к нему, допустим: hello. Но если пользователь напишет Hello, то php поймет это уже как не верный ответ, ибо H - заглавная. Как убрать эту чувствительность к регистру?

Comment: @Эдуард Исправил, так понятнее?

Comment: Нет, не понятно чем вас не устроила штатная функция преобразования в нижний регистр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = "Mary Had A Little Lamb and She LOVED It So";
$str = strtolower($str);
echo $str; // выводит: mary had a little lamb and she loved it so
?>
```