# Поставить фильтр на сайте

Tags: php

Я хочу поставить фильтр на тег , чтобы пользователь не мог вбить в textarea/input и т.п. какой то скрипт, который может навредить сайту. А также сделать замену <> и & на их спецсимволы (для тех же целей). Но я никогда не писал каких-то таких фильтров и не знаю, как это делается. Как это реализовать? (По возможности на php, а не js)

Comment: А что на счёт [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980476/Вопрос-по-регистру-при-обработке-кода-php)?

Comment: @Эдуард ответы прописаны нижним регистром, $gap1 = strtolower($_POST['gap1']); и все работает. Просто немного не в правильном порядке написал изначально, подумав, что это не то